# I am getting this error in free pascal when compiling (Fatal: can't find unit crt used by ex2)

Tags: compiler-errors, pascal, freepascal

I have been working on pascal language as it is in my high school syllabus. I have been doing some coding to see how it works. so far (for more than a month) I didn't get any error's except for my own syntax errors (this was when I was coding in Free Pascal),since I was doig pretty well I thought of going more advanced and started coding (today) with Sublime Text editor and to compile the code in Free Pascal. But it seems that an error message is popping.

What could be the reason? would love to have your assistance!

[image: screenshot of the error message shown]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is a mis- or non-configuration of Free Pascal.

Crt is an unit outside of the lowest level RTL, and while the compiler can often guess the RTL location, it won't add additional rows.

Make sure your fpc.cfg is set up correctly and contains something like

```
# searchpath for units and other system dependent things
-FuC:\FPC\3.2.2/units/$fpctarget
-FuC:\FPC\3.2.2/units/$fpctarget/*
-FuC:\FPC\3.2.2/units/$fpctarget/rtl
```

And that Sumblime doesn't call FPC with -n (to ignore config file).

added later:

Ok. That is "fp", the textmode IDE, not FPC the commandline compiler. The textmode IDE has its own compiler builtin (one solid binary so to say), and has its own path. Enter the path with the asterisk from the -Fu settings into options->directories->unit path.

If you want a more 21st century IDE, consider Lazarus.